# How to map j/k to <Up>/<Down> for an [ncurses] application only, under terminal emulator?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

When `make menuconfig`, I would like to use <kbd>j</kbd>/<kbd>k</kbd> to select item below/above current one, just as <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> do. How to achieve that? (I use tmux under both gnome-terminal and cygwin mintty.)

My first thought is something like below, using bash function,

```
vmake () {
    # remap j/k
    make "$@";
    # undo remapping
}
```

though I do not know how to fill the details, and of course other/better solution exist.

Comment: Given those constraints, any solution will have to lie in what tmux can (or can't) do.

Comment: @Thomas Can you please elaborate a little more, does usage of tmux make it much harder? I initially assume tmux make little difference here. Besides, **a solution works on linux gnome-terminal only is well-appreciated too**, such as those `setxkbmap` or `xmodmap` ones.